# How to save data to multiple models with one form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

a pretty noob here. I am trying to create a user profile at the time when the account is created using signals. I want all the fields of the user profile to be filled in sign up page.
This is the user profile that I am trying to populate:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, default="0331232132")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my custom user model here:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")
        email =  self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        kwargs.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        kwargs.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)



class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

This is my user creation form that I am sending to template:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Confirm Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    name = forms.CharField()
    contact_number = forms.CharField(
                        max_length=11
                    )
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['email']
```

I am not sure if it is relevant but this is my custom email backend.

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

Now what I want is when the user submits the user creation form, Email and Password field is used to create a user account while name and contact number along with the newly created user object are used to create a userprofile instance using signals. All the examples that I have seen till now only handle setting only the user object in profile.

Comment: Since you said you're a noob, I want to suggest that instead of using a UserProfile, you could just add those extra fields to your User model. Doing it that way makes things much simpler.

Comment: Hey thankyou for your response. I have already implemented and tested what you are suggesting but I want to try a new thing. Can you suggest some other solution specific to my problem.